# Passing jQuery paramenter between pages

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to pass variables between php pages with jQuery.

My code: I am using this on fullcalendar.js API:

First page: EventMain.php

```
select: function (start, end) {

   $.ajax({
      url: '/dev/Event/Event.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {name: 'John'}
   });

  PopupCenter(url,'Event', 1000, 450)
}
```

Then the pop open with a second Page: Event.php. I need to get the name variable

```
var Name = <? php echo $_POST['name']; ?>;

alert(Name);
```

The alert is blank.. I don't understand why?

I know I can send the variables on the url as parameters and then on Event.php use getUrlParameter to get the variables:

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam){
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't want to send the variables on the url. Is there any other way to send the variable?

Comment: how the alert is showing via ajax request?

Comment: For starters your Name = part should be quoted '<?php ...?>'; otherwise you'll get a JS error. Use firebug NET panel to see the response you get back. I doubt you'd be able to trigger an alert on an ajax call and I'd expect the AJAX call to do an update - you could then output within PHP and view it in the NET panel.

Comment: The alert is not showing via ajax request. I send the variable from the EventMain.php to Event.php by ajax and then a should be able to read it in php $_POST on the Event.php. But it's not working. Do you guys think that as something to do with the async?

Comment: It's not related to the asynchronous activity. The popup opens a page with a new session. The AJAX call is another session, so it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access POST variables in another session.

The popup you open is a new request to a page that doesn't have the data.

There is no reasonable solution to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So is there any other to pass variables between pages in jquery other than on the url as parameters?

Comment: If you wan't to pass variables to PHP to use in a later request, save the data you post to a session. You cannot access the data in an asynchronous way.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the variable from `EventMain.php` to  `Event.php`

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url : '/dev/Event/Event.php',
         data: { name : 'John'},
         success: function(response) {   // return content from Event.php (result) page
                // Do your operation with result
          }
  });
```

In Event.php

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
// Perform your actions with $name and return result as
echo $yourresult;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as to *why* the attempt doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is that I need to work with the variable in jquery on Event.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way ...

**eventMain.php**

```
$.post('/dev/Event/Event.php',{'name':'John'}, function(data){
   // do something with response 
});
```

**Event.php**

```
<?php
   $name = $_POST['name'];
 ?>

<script>
   console.log('<?= $name; ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: That works. But I still cannot access $name in jQuery on Event.php.

Comment: you can use it in `javascript` .. or ( `jQuery` if you have it in `Event.php`)  see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the `""` when assign a value to variable `name` in the second page.

**First Page:**

```
<!-- you don't forget this tag to see the result //-->
<div id="content"></div>

$.ajax({
    url: 'page.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {name: 'John'},
    success: function (data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
    }
});
```

**Second Page (event.php):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = "<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>";
    alert(name);
</script>
```

The previous code work for me, I've tested it.